# Restoring a database to a point in time

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Has anyone got an explicit set of instructions to restore a database to a specific time and date? 17:00 today in fact! A table has been wiped and the maintenance plan is of no use. Thanks. However if the recovery model is BULK-LOGGED and not FULL is this going to stop this idea dead in its tracks?